# Navigation Drawer Menu on Android 2.X - Small Screens

Tags: android, user-experience

I have recently coded an application and included a DrawerLayout with the [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) pattern. This application must support ldpi/small devices and android version 2.1+ for market share reasons.

One user made an observation about the Drawer Menu icon looking 'cut' and the app being hard to navigate because of this. I guess this is expected, considering that all mayor apps (Twitter, Instagram, Gmail, etc) haven't updated the app for this kind of devices. Though,   they are using this pattern for newer/bigger devices/platforms.

Considering that the DrawerLayout has been included in the support library, i would expect apps to start backporting it to 2.X sooner or later. Maybe big players haven't done it because <strike>Google officially deprecated LDPI</strike> ldpi/small devices are rare nowadays and [even unsupported for some community tools](https://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/issues/detail?id=175), but what would be the right thing to do in order for the app to be successful in this matter? Is there any guideline to follow on this topic? If you have to support ldpi/small and 2.X, would you go with a drawer navigation menu? why?

Thanks for your comments.

[Edit]

Went too far, for some reasons i thought Google actually deprecated LDPI/small, but it was just some community tools/libs that i've seen around that actually did it. Even the ADT template doesn't generate the drawables for LDPI/small.

Comment: Did your app provided a drawer icon for ldpi?

Comment: Yes, i did. I have actually tested myself on an ldpi device and it looks good. But i guess the question is more oriented to whether the patter is known and used in older devices/platforms, and whether we should expect those users to know how to use it. Thanks!

Comment: "Even the ADT template doesn't generate the drawables for LDPI" -- that's because, in many cases, downsampling `-mdpi` drawables gives adequate results. You will notice that ADT does not generate `-tvdpi` drawables either, despite that being the density used by the 1st generation Nexus 7. That's because downsampling `-hdpi` drawables to `-tvdpi` is frequently sufficient.

Comment: Try with some otherlib then.. Try [this](https://github.com/korovyansk/android-fb-like-slideout-navigation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Considering that the DrawerLayout has been included in the support library, i would expect apps to start backporting it to 2.X sooner or later

I wouldn't. A redesign that adds in a nav drawer is a fairly substantial redesign, and I would expect most developers doing such a redesign to ignore Android 2.x entirely. At most, they might worry about Android 2.3, and even then only for a short while.

> Maybe big players haven't done it because Google officially deprecated LDPI

I am not aware that "Google officially deprecated LDPI".

> If you have to support ldpi and 2.X, would you go with a drawer navigation menu?

Personally, no, because [~90% of `-ldpi` devices are `-small` devices](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), and I suspect that you will find that you have to make some substantial UI compromises for `-small` screens. Even an action bar may be too much "chrome" for such screens.

> But i guess the question is more oriented to whether the patter is known and used in older devices/platforms, and whether we should expect those users to know how to use it.

Probably not. Overall, I would expect them to be less than completely familiar with the action bar, because fewer apps on `-small` devices would use it, due to limited screen space. I would expect there to be few apps who use an action bar *and* a nav drawer on `-small` devices.

That being said, [the navigation drawer design documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) covers discoverability. Getting some of that to work on a `-small` screen may be dicey, but it is at least worth investigating.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I was actually wrong about Google deprecating LDPI. I got confused with a few libs/tools. Going back to the question, your point of view makes sense, but what if you have to support LDPI in the same APK that you are using for all the version? Would you go with a completely different navigation just for LDPI?  Thanks again.

Comment: @RobertEstivill: IMHO, the issue is not screen density, but screen *size*. "Going with a totally different navigation... might be a considerable amount of work" -- yes, which is why many smaller development shops do not bother supporting the `-small` screen size. While they leave out ~10% of the market, it is *only* ~10%, and they focus on the rest. You need to decide which is best *for your business*: skip `-small` entirely, use the nav drawer on small (at potential usability cost), do something else for `-small` other than the nav drawer, or skip the nav drawer entirely for all sizes.